# how to get center of screen Coordinates in android Mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox

how can i get center of screen 
Coordinates in android mapbox

```
public void setMarker(double lat,double lng){
        sourceLat = lat;
        sourceLng = lng;
        map.setSourcePin(lat , lng);
        map.flyTo(lat, lng);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double mapLat = mapboxMap.getCameraPosition().target.getLatitude()

double mapLong = mapboxMap.getCameraPosition().target.getLongitude()
```

**Edit:** The center of the map is the `target`. The `MapboxMap` class has a `getCameraPosition()` method and the `Target` class within the `CameraPosition` class.

```
LatLng mapLatLng = mapboxMap.getCameraPosition().target;
double mapLat = mapLatLng.getLatitude();
double mapLong = mapLatLng.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In mapbox 10 it is a bit different :
following are 2 ways to achieve this functionality :

the short way (inspired by langsmith)

```
val point:Point? = mapboxMap?.cameraState?.center
```

Long way :

```
val x = (find<View>(mapContainerViewId()).width / 2).toDouble()
val y = find<View>(mapContainerViewId()).height / 2.toDouble()
val point:Point?  = mapboxMap?.coordinateForPixel(ScreenCoordinate(x,y))
```